# How can I check if the ground below me is moving?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

If my character controller is standing on top of an object that is moving, how can I move my controller in the direction that the object below is moving in without using parenting?

Currently I use SetParent() but it causes unexpected issues like scale and rotation issues with the controller and there's weird movement with this method. When I remove my parenting code, my controller just stands on top of the rotating object and does not move.

[image]

```
public Transform rotateObj; 
public GameObject Player;
Vector3 lastPos;
bool isRotating;

void Start()
{
    lastPos = rotateObj.transform.position; // rotating object transform
}

void Update()
{
    transform.Rotate(RotateAmount * speed * Time.deltaTime);

    if (rotateObj.transform.position != lastPos)
    {
        isRotating = true;
    }
    else
    {
        isRotating = false;
    }

    if (isRotating == true)
    {
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, 1.2f))
        {
            // Player.transform.position ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `unexpected issues like scale and rotation`. I think you can disable that behaviour; [doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html)s.

Comment: Yeah I've tried to use worldPositionStays and set the bool so that the scale would remain untouched, but I couldn't get it to work using the code in the docs

Comment: What is your target? You have a character moving around in space and it should be influenced by moving objects that it is standing (or moving itself) on?

Comment: Does your object have a rigidbody attached to it?

Comment: If the moving platform has Rigidbody you can get its velocity and add it to the character standing on it.

Comment: @DevAm00 sorry for the late response. I am using the in-built character controller so I have no rigidbody attached. I tried several things, the rotating object at first had a rigidbody with is Kinematic ON, a capsule collider/mesh collider and also tried having no rigidbody attached.

Answer (score 0):

So I wrote some quick dummy code to illustrate how you could achieve this. I did not test this code, or open Unity so please only use it as a rough reference.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 _groundMovement;

    private void Update() 
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -transform.up, out hit, 1.2f, layerMask))
        {
            // GetComponent is fairly expensive, so in a proper implementation you would cache the collider, and compare it to the current value to see if it has changed.
            var rotatingGround = hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<IMovingGround>();
            if (rotatingGround != null)
            {
                _groundMovement = rotatingGround.RotateAmountSinceLastFrame;
            }
        }

        // Get Input
        // Calculate player movement from input
        // Apply player movement

        // Apply Ground Movement
        transform.position += _groundMovement;
    }
}
```

```
using UnityEngine;

public class RotatingGroundObject : MonoBehaviour, IMovingGround
{
    public Vector3 lastRot;
    public Vector3 RotateAmountSinceLastFrame { get; private set; }

    void Start()
    {
        lastRot = this.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        transform.Rotate(RotateAmount * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        RotateAmountSinceLastFrame = transform.rotation.eulerAngles - lastRot;
        lastRot = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
    }
}
```

One caveat to consider is, that if you are using Rigidbodies or any Physics you will need to apply your movement in FixedUpdate() to avoid any weird behaviour. For simplicities sake, I put it all in Update in this example code.
Additionally, applying the rotation value directly to the movement is probably not what you want. You would have to do Vector math to apply the movement in your desired direction according to the rotation value.
The interface IMovingGround would help, if you have multiple moving ground objects with different functionality, like moving platforms, rotating platforms etc.
Let me know if you need any more details, or help!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. When you said "cache the collider" could I not just add an "OnTriggerEnter (Collider col)" in that case, and then use the 'col' to check for lastPos?

Comment: Yeah for sure, this would replace the raycast in Update(), which actually is a great idea. Usually you have a raycast anyway if you're building a character controller though, since you need to know about ground normals for handling slopes etc. 
If you are using the built in character controller, or do not have slopes in your game the OnTriggerEnter() version / a combination of both will work as well.

Comment: Yeah I have a SphereCast & Raycast already for slope detection using Vector3.SignedAngle and Vector3.Angle, etc, just not sure how I would use my hit.normal to check for moving ground, unless I use the 'GetComponent" above